# Weird \nocite{*} behaviour with bibtex & beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I'm using BibTeX together with latex beamer and have a weird issue:

the entries of my BibTeX file look like this one:

```
    @inproceedings{DBLP:conf/latin/BenderF00,
      author    = {Michael A. Bender and
           Martin Farach-Colton},
      title     = {The {LCA} Problem Revisited},
      booktitle = {LATIN},
      year      = {2000},
      pages     = {88-94},
      ee        = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/10719839_9},
      crossref  = {DBLP:conf/latin/2000},
      bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
    } 
    @proceedings{DBLP:conf/latin/2000,
     editor    = {Gaston H. Gonnet and
                  Daniel Panario and
                  Alfredo Viola},
     title     = {LATIN 2000: Theoretical Informatics, 4th Latin American
                  Symposium, Punta del Este, Uruguay, April 10-14, 2000,            Proceedings},
     booktitle = {LATIN},
     publisher = {Springer},
     series    = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
     volume    = {1776},
     year      = {2000},
     isbn      = {3-540-67306-7},
     bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
     }
```

using `\cite{DBLP:conf/latin/BenderF00}` together with

```
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
    \begin{scriptsize}
     %\nocite{*}  // commented out!!!!!!!!
     \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
     \bibliographystyle{alpha}
     \bibliography{literatur}
    \end{scriptsize}
    \end{frame}
```

gives me:

> [BFC00] Michael A. Bender and Martin Farach-Colton. The LCA problem revisited. In Gaston H. Gonnet, Daniel Panario, and Alfredo Viola, editors, LATIN, volume 1776 of Lecture Notes in Computer Science, pages 88–94. Springer, 2000.

which is perfect.

But when i don't cite `\cite{DBLP:conf/latin/BenderF00}` explicitly and use `\nocite{*}` instead i have the following result:

> [BFC00] Michael A. Bender and Martin Farach-Colton. The LCA problem revisited. In Gonnet et al. **[GPV00]**, pages 88–94.

**with a new reference to [GPV00]** and so on...

How can i avoid that behaviour? I'm pleased about every advice

Comment: `\nocite{*}` adds everything in your bib-file to the bibliography, that's what it supposed to do. `\nocite{DBLP:conf/latin/BenderF00}` adds just that reference.

Comment: Ah, i understand the problem! Is it possible to 'let the references being resolved' automatically? (assume a very large .bib file)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, can you clarify? If you just want some entries from a .bib-file in the bibliography, you have to `\cite` or `\nocite` those entries.

Comment: i have a huge bib file and only ``\cite`` some entries but want all of them listed (in the aforementioned form) at the bibliography section at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\nocite{*}` you're basically adding a `\nocite` command for every entry in the bibliography database. When BibTeX finds `\nocite` (or `\cite`) relative both to a `@inproceedings` item and its cross-referenced `@proceedings` item, it adds both entries in the bibliography, with a reference (in your case “[GPV00]”) in the `@inproceedings` item.

So, with `\cite{DBLP:conf/latin/BenderF00}`, without `\nocite{*}`, the `@proceedings` entry is used for filling data in that item. But, if there were another item cross-referencing `DBLP:conf/latin/2000`, this entry would appear by itself anyway (see [*Tame the BeaST*](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf), section 12).

There is no `\nocite` command that avoids cross-referenced only items.

In the case of a huge database to show, I'd go with this default method. The alternative is getting all the keys, removing those that appear in a `crossref` field and do a `\nocite` with the explicit list of keys.